# How to use current file as parameter to Run configuration in pycharm

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

I want to create custom run configurations, but i cannot figure out how to get the current file name as a parameter...

I would like to do something like this:

`py.test -m mymarker %f`

`autopep8 %f`

where `%f` is the current file name.

Comment: Run/Debug configurations work with specific stuff only: i.e. you provide file name/folder and it's saved as part of that Configuration -- they do not support parameters/path macros (like External Tools). To do what you want you may edit corresponding configuration under **Defaults branch** .. and then if you use "Run" via content menu that default config will be used for every new Run/Debug Configuration.

Comment: @LazyOne that cannot be, since you can right-click anywhere and run configurations. their documentation is just horrible.

Comment: @LazyOne.  Sad to say but it looksike you are still right, seven years later.  I wish JetBrains would understand how annoying this is to new and veteran users alike.   I can do the right thing in VisualStudio

Comment: @CharlesMerriam 2022.2 now has "Current File" type of Run/Debug Configuration that always follows currently edited (or perhaps focused) file. Plus **some** (not all) types of configuration now also support macros in some of the fields (mainly params/arguments -- where you see `+` kind of icon inside the field)) where you can use `$FileName$` and alike macro there (that get resolved at run time).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer by Ctrl+C already hints at $FileName$ and at least in the current version 2020.2 of PyCharm this works in Run Configurations.

1. Create a run configuration as you desire, e.g. `Python`
2. In `Parameters` field you can simply use macros like `$FileName$` or `$FilePath$`. Or click on the `+` at the right end for a full list
3. Hit the Run button or `Shift+F10` by default while your target file is opened

Answer (score 2):

What you want to insert there is called a *macro*, which is a context-dependent variable: `$FileName$` (current file in this case). Unfortunately this doesn't work yet in **Run** configurations.

**Workaround - use External Tools**

1. Settings > Tools > External Tools
2. [+]
3. set "Program" as path to your script/program ('py.test')
4. in "Arguments" use button [Insert Macro...] on the right. There will be a list of possibilities. For example you wanted `$FileName$` for the current file.

If you want both of those commands in one External Tool command, then create a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash -exu

py.test -m mymarker $@
autopep8 $@
```

Finally you can use it via [Tools]>[External Tools], [Right click on a file]>[External Tools] or you can add a shortcut to the command.

Answer (score 1):

I solved similar problems with Ruby as shown in screenshot link below.
After that: right click on script-file, select in Pop-up menu External Tools -> [Your runner]

[image: Configuration Ruby runner]